# How to change datatype using replace function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

```
select
    replace(Street, char(10), '')
from streettable
```

Have explored the syntax of `replace` function ...but how does this piece of code work?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? REPLACE is usually used to change the content of a value rather than its type.

Comment: This is not changing the type, in this case `CHAR(10)` is not defining a type of `CHAR` with a length of 10, is it the [scalar function `CHAR()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx) returning the ASCII character 10 (line feed).

Answer (score 3):

The sample code doesn't change datatype. `char(10)` is `line feed` and the code just replaces `line feeds` with empty symbol in `street` column(not in table, but on the fly to present. Data in table stays untouched).

If you want to change datatype then you should alter the column. Something like:

```
alter table streettable alter column Street varchar(777) null
```